# " ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked" error when making test in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is from the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Web Development with Rails 7th edition" chapter 11, and I noticed when I remove the following test:

```
test 'should not be able to log in with invalid email' do
    get edit_account_activation_path(@user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
  end
```

I get green result and the test works, but when I add it, it gives me a lot of errors with the same error message :

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
```

This is the complete class that includes that test, and it seems when I remove some other test and keep the one above I get green, as if those test together produces the problem :

```
class AccountActivationTest < UsersSignup

  def setup
    super
    post users_path, params: { user: {name: 'Example User',
                                email: 'user@example.com',
                                password:   'password',
                                password_confirmation: 'password'}}
    @user = assigns(:user)
  end

  test 'should not be activated' do
    assert_not @user.activated?

  end

  test 'should not be able to log in before account activation' do
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_not is_logged_in?
  end

  test 'should not be able to log in with invalid email' do
    get edit_account_activation_path(@user.activation_token, email: 'wrong')
    assert_not is_logged_in?
  end

  test 'should log in successfully with valid activation token and email' do
    get edit_account_activation_path(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)
    assert @user.reload.activated?
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

Comment: SQLite is not great at concurrent operations.  Try adding ```timeout: 1000``` to your database.yml to give it a little space to breath before tossing an error.

Comment: @dbugger I changed it to 1000 but still gave me the same errors